# Two Cron jobs at the same time - one not working

Tags: cron, python

First of all I am not very familiar with `cron`... Under `.../cron/crontabs` I have a file (which is called `root`, not sure whether it needs to be the same as the user?) with one job:

```
* * * * * sleep 0; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
* * * * * sleep 10; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
* * * * * sleep 20; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
...
```

And this **works**: it downloads the contents of the IP address and saves into my file every 10 seconds. There are other three commands with `sleep` 30, 40 and 50.

---

Now I want to add another job that executes a python script every 10 seconds.

I tried to create a new file under `.../cron/crontabs`, which I called `job2` but nothing happened.

- can I just create as many cron scripts as I want? Do I need to start them somehow?

---

Since this did not work, I tried to add my second job to the existing `root` file, which now reads:

```
* * * * * sleep 0; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
* * * * * /home/user/Documents/pythonscript
* * * * * sleep 10; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
* * * * * /home/user/Documents/pythonscript
* * * * * sleep 20; wget -0 /var/cache/file.txt 'IP-ADDRESS'
* * * * * /home/user/Documents/pythonscript
...
```

where `pythonscript` is an executable, and I made sure that the cron folder has permissions to the python script path...

- This still does not work. How do I make cron execture a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have only one crontab per user, and its filename is the username.

Also, the proper way to edit it is to run `crontab -e` -- it's entirely possible that the cron daemon doesn't notice you've changed the file directly.
Just call `crontab -e`now, it will open your editor with the crontab, and it will reload the config after you save and exit, and your other jobs should start running.

Comment: When I type <code>crontab -e</code> I just see a number...?

Comment: I actually found the answer... I just add to first change the directory to the one where my script lives, then exectute it...

Comment: By the way do you know what exactly <cron> crontab -e </code> is supposed to return? I have two machines, and on one it gives a number (random?) and on the other it makes me see and modify the crontab file with commands.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: it will open your preferred editor (as given in the environment variable `EDITOR` or `VISUAL`) with the crontab file (I think technically a temporary copy of it which it copies back afterwards) and reload the crontab when the editor exists.

Comment: So why do I get a number out?

Comment: @SuperCiocia it's probably because the default `EDITOR` is set to `ed`: see for example [Crontab error “No crontab for root”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420290/crontab-error-no-crontab-for-root). The number is likely a linecount of the current crontab file.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What’s the point of having different cron jobs for different users? Like will the one for root not work until I’ve logged in as root, I.e. put the password?